# Error 1045 using password yes and restore data from wampserver

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have wamp running locally on my computer and was working just fine. I have a web application based on PHP and MySQL. I am using a password for the connection.

Suddenly, I got the following error:

> MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

I tried to follow the answers of this [post on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw). But nothing worked.

Ounce I open the mysql cmd and write down the password, it will close immediately.

I even used MySQL workbench, and I was successful to enter but on a different user with password. But the user I am using where my databases resides, is not accessible anymore.

I have a db called ncd, where I can see it on the other user but as empty.

Could I restore the data from wampserver ?

Comment: Are you sure you dont have 2 MySQL Servers running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your db on /mysql/ folder and them store it. And move to another mysql with another account and restore your db with same folder as above me talk it.

Comment: There is files with `.frm` and `.ibd`. So I will create a new folder with these files, then create a user ?

Comment: In my pc the db is store at C:\MAMP\db\mysql. And can you FLUSH PRIVILAGES after moving to the new fresh account?

Comment: Yes, this is encrypted and only can opened by mysql client such as phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ok thanks sir. I will work on it directly. But still don't know why some people down voted me after someone upvoted.

Comment: do not take the feeling, keep trying when you meet the deadlock, ask here 

Comment: Thanks sir. Appreciate the words.

Comment: I took the backuped files into a new folder and created a db with the same name. The tables are now seen inside the database but when I click on a table, it said `table does not exist`