# Backup files from wamp shows tables but an error saying table does not exist

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238812/error-1045-using-password-yes-and-restore-data-from-wampserver/51238865) in the morning. But when I tried what I've been told to do by checking db on /mysql/ folder and them store it. And move to another mysql with another account and restore db with same folder as above.

Now my issue is the following:

I took the backup-ed files into a new folder and created a db with the same name. The tables are now seen inside the database but when I click on a table, it said table does not exist.

Comment: Is your database MYISAM or INNODB? If it is INNODB you cannot do what the answer to your other question suggests

Comment: yes it's INNODB.

Comment: Did you look in the `\wamp\log\mysql error.log` to see if that tells you anything about your original issue?